# Tiring App to a USB Sticks.

Tags: java, usb-flash-drive

I am required to tied an app to a USB stick (A flash drive). It is a desktop app which can only run from a usb stick sold by the vendor of the application and none other. Is there any method i can use in achieving this (in java)? Maybe a better understanding of how best to tied the app to a usb flash drive would do

Comment: To be clear, you don't want the user to be able to copy what's on the usb flash drive into another usb stick or to the computer itself and be able to run the app there? (Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by "tieing")

Comment: even if they re able to copy to another usb device, it still wouldn't work except on the usb sold by the vendor